# Замена символа не работает

Tags: javascript

Есть предложение что то | так так

```
var a = b.replace(/|/g, '%7C');
```

Почему не заменяет только | на %7C, а заменяет после каждой буквы на %7C

Answer (score 3):

Экранируйте "|". Но, мне кажется, Вы не к месту используете регулярные выражения.

```js
var b = "aa|aa|aa";
var a = b.replace(/\|/g, '%7C');
var c = encodeURIComponent(b);
console.log(b, a, c);
```

Comment: Это экранирование ?

Comment: @MegaRoks, в контексте регулярных выражений `|` читается как "или" (то есть, что угодно или что угодно), если заэкранировать `\|`, то это будет просто литералом

Comment: спасибо, я пытался экранировать так  `|