# Замены в строке

Tags: javascript

К примеру в переменной `text` есть строка  `https://yandex.ru/search/?text=текст` и делаю одну замену `:` на `%20`, можно ли сделать, не приберегая к созданию под каждую замену переменных?

```
function delete_for_text(text){
    var not_text = text.replace(/:/g, '%20');
    return not_text;
}
```

Как можно принять переменную `text` заменить `/` на `%3A`, `?` на `&app`, `=` на `#ty` в одной функции и вернуть уже отформатированный текст в переменной `not_text`?

Answer (score 2):

Я уже говорил Вам, что надо использовать: [Замена символа не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817409), но Вы продолжаете упорствовать и заменять по одному символу. Вы не учтете всех случаев, о которых подумали люди, писавшие `encodeURIComponent`.

```js
var a = "https://yandex.ru/search/?text=текст";
var b = encodeURIComponent(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Это ж вроде не соответствует требованиям вопроса заменять `:` на `%20`, ну и далее там совсем экзотические замены перечислены. :)